# How to replace characters from string starting from some index

Tags: c#

i want to replace all characters after 16 number of characters and replace it with `...` how to do this any idea?

```
string foo = "something is going to happen";

output i want like this: "something is goi..."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `Length` property of the input string, and if it's longer than 16 characters, use the `Substring` method to get the first part of the string and add the ellipses to it, otherwise just use the input as-is:

```
string output = foo.Length > 16 ? foo.Substring(0, 16) + "..." : foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1) method to do this.

```cs
string foo = "something is going to happen";

string output = "";

if (foo.Length > 16)
    output = foo.Substring(0, 16) + "...";
else
    output = foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to truncate a string and multiples ways to append.

```
string foo = "something is going to happen";
string output = foo;
if (foo.Length > 16)
{
    //use one of these:
    //output = foo.Substring(0, 16) + "..."; //Substring
    output = foo.Remove(16) + "..."; //Remove
    //output = foo[.. 16] + "..."; //Range, from C# 8
}
```